# license for a multichat application ? contact information ?

Tags: license

I'm creating a multi chat application that communicate with different bridges ( yahoo, msn , gtalk and Facebook) using libpurple .

How am I supposed to get a license or approval from the above companies ? any contact information ? anyone has a knowledge of that since i'm from technical backgrounds .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need one.  If libpurple is able to communicate with thse networks its for a reason.  In the case of most of those companies, they epxose their own api.  If you got doubts about this response contact the companies themselfs.

Comment: thanks for that , I just wanted to be sure about it since i don't want them to stop the service after lunching it , I will contact libpurple and ask the community there , thanks